# Ray picking mess

Tags: opengl, ray-picking

I am using ray picking to find the boundaries for a character. It's not optimal, but it's the best I can do and will have to do; I need to have (close to) pixelperfect collisions and also I have lots and lots of objects.

I do not however get the raypicking to work correctly. It collides, but not at the right places. I tried adjust the size of the ray, and more to no avail.

Excuse me for the messy code, I just threw it together.

```
private void renderCollision(Vector3f dir){
    //
    // Render the models
    //

    glPushMatrix();
    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

    float size = 10.0f;
    Picker.startPicking2D(10, 10, 20, 20, -1.0f, size);
    //Picker.startPicking2D(10, 10, 20, 20, 0.1f, 20.0f);

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthMask(true);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(100.0f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glLoadIdentity (); 


    //box.drawMoving(camera);
    player.move(dir);
    glTranslatef(-player.position.x, -player.position.y + size / 2.0f, -player.position.z);
    glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    box.drawAll();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    boolean hit = Picker.getHit();
    if (hit) {
        player.move(new Vector3f(-dir.x, -dir.y, -dir.z));
    }

    Picker.stopPicking();

    glPopAttrib();
    glPopMatrix();
}

public class Picker {

    private static IntBuffer selBuffer;
    private static int hits;

    private static int xSelected;
    private static int ySelected;

    /**
     * Makes the game available for picking (when in 3D mode)
     *
     * @param xMouse The x coordinate of the mouse on the screen
     * @param yMouse The y coordinate of the mouse on the screen
     */
    public static void startPicking3D(int xMouse, int yMouse, int screenWidth, int screenHeight, float near, float far) {
        startPickingGeneric(xMouse, yMouse);

        GLU.gluPerspective(SCREEN_FOV, SCREEN_RAT,
                           near, far);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    /**
     * Makes the game available for picking (when in 2D mode)
     *
     * @param xMouse The x coordinate of the mouse on the screen
     * @param yMouse The y coordinate of the mouse on the screen
     */
    public static void startPicking2D(int xMouse, int yMouse, int screenWidth, int screenHeight, float near, float far) {
        startPickingGeneric(xMouse, yMouse);

        GL11.glOrtho(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, near, far);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    /**
     * Makes the game available for picking (generic)
     *
     * @param xMouse The x coordinate of the mouse on the screen
     * @param yMouse The y coordinate of the mouse on the screen
     */
    private static void startPickingGeneric(int xMouse, int yMouse){
        // The selection buffer
        selBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).
                    asIntBuffer();
        IntBuffer vpBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64).
                             order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
        // Size of the viewport. [0] Is <x>, [1] Is <y>, [2] Is <width>, [3] Is <height>
        int[] viewport = new int[4];

        // Get the viewport info
        GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, vpBuffer);
        vpBuffer.get(viewport);

        // Set the buffer that OpenGL uses for selection to our buffer
        GL11.glSelectBuffer(selBuffer);

        // Change to selection mode
        GL11.glRenderMode(GL11.GL_SELECT);

        // Initialize the name stack (used for identifying which object was selected)
        GL11.glInitNames();

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        // Create 5x5 pixel picking region near cursor location
        GLU.gluPickMatrix((float) xMouse, (float) yMouse,
                          5.0f, 5.0f, IntBuffer.wrap(viewport));
    }

    /**
     * Stops the picking mode
     */
    public static void stopPicking(){
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        hits = 0;
        hits = GL11.glRenderMode(GL11.GL_RENDER);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the tile the mouse points to
     *
     * @return TileCoords object with the coordinates of the selected tile
     */
    public static boolean getHit(){

        int[] buffer = new int[256];
        xSelected = -1000;
        ySelected = -1000;

        selBuffer.get(buffer);

        if (hits > 0) {
              // If there were more than 0 hits
              xSelected = buffer[3]; // Make our selection the first object
              ySelected = buffer[4];
              int depth = buffer[1]; // Store how far away it is
              for (int i = 1; i < hits; i++) {
                    // Loop through all the detected hits
                    // If this object is closer to us than the one we have selected
                    if (buffer[i * 4 + 1] < (int) depth) {
                        xSelected = buffer[i * 4 + 3]; // Select the closest object
                        ySelected = buffer[i * 4 + 4];
                        depth = buffer[i * 4 + 1]; // Store how far away it is
                     }
              }
              return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: "**pickelperfect** collisions"?

Comment: @gepfault: Yeah, as green as a pickel :')

Comment: Don't use the fixed function pipeline!

Comment: @Felix K.: I just read about this, it's kinda debatable apparently but newer graphics cards can indeed be faster with shaders. I will keep it in mind if I drastically need the performance boost. Thanks!

Comment: @RobotRock There are some other reasons, not only about performance, but you are more flexible and, which is the main reason, the ffp is deprecated.

Comment: @Felix K.: Yeah, I use more deprecated functions, it's not good, however the deprecated functions/ways are much better documented I have the idea.

Comment: @RobotRock I know, most OpenGL functions are not really good documented you could read the whitepaper but theese are most times really huge. However there are some good tutorials on shaders and vertex buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should rotate around x-axis instead of y-axis and then translate.